# How to make this SQL query more efficient and how to do more

Tags: sql, ruby, sqlite, duplicates

I have a sqlite3 database in which I have corrupt data. I qualify "corrupt" with the following characteristics:

Data in name, telephone, latitude, longitude columns is corrupt if: The value is NULL or "" or length < 2

Data in address column is corrupt if The value is NULL or "" or number of words < 2 and length of word is <2

To test this I wrote the following script in Ruby:

```
require 'sqlite3'

db = SQLite3::Database.new('development.sqlite3')

db.results_as_hash = true;

#Checks for empty strings in name, address, telephone, latitude, longitude
#Also checks length of strings is valid
rows = db.execute(" SELECT * FROM listings WHERE LENGTH('telephone') < 2 OR LENGTH('fax') < 2  OR LENGTH('address') < 2 OR LENGTH('city') < 2 OR LENGTH('province') < 2 OR LENGTH('postal_code') < 2 OR LENGTH('latitude') < 2 OR LENGTH('longitude') < 2 
OR name = '' OR address = '' OR telephone = '' OR latitude = '' OR longitude = '' ") 

rows.each do |row|
=begin
db.execute("INSERT INTO missing (id, name, telephone, fax, suite, address, city, province, postal_code, latitude, longitude, url) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", row['id'], row['name'], row['telephone'], row['fax'], row['suite'], row['address'], row['city'], row['province'],
row['postal_code'], row['latitude'], row['longitude'], row['url'] )
=end

  id_num = row['id']
  puts "Id = #{id_num}"

  corrupt_name = row['name']
  puts "name = #{corrupt_name}"

  corrupt_address = row['address']
  puts "address = #{corrupt_address}"

  corrupt_tel = row['telephone']
  puts "tel = #{corrupt_tel}"

  corrupt_lat = row['latitude']
  puts "lat = #{corrupt_lat}" 

  corrupt_long = row['longitude']
  puts "lat = #{corrupt_long}" 
  puts '===end===='

end
#After inserting the records into the new table delete them from the old table
=begin
db.execute(" DELETE * FROM listings WHERE LENGTH('telephone') < 2 OR LENGTH('fax') < 2  OR LENGTH('address') < 2 OR 
LENGTH('city') < 2 OR LENGTH('province') < 2 OR LENGTH('postal_code') < 2 OR LENGTH('latitude') < 2 OR LENGTH('longitude') < 2 
OR name = '' OR address = '' OR telephone = '' OR latitude = '' OR longitude = '' ")
=end
```

This works but Im new to Ruby and DB programming. So I would welcome any suggestions to make this query better.
The ultimate goal I have is to run a script on my database which tests the validity of data in it and if there are some data that are not valid they are copied to a different table and deleted from the 1st table.

Also, I would like to add to this query a test to check for duplicate entries.

I qualify an entry as duplicate if more than 1 rows share the same name and the same address and the same telephone and the same latitude and the same longitude

I came up with this query but Im not sure if its the most optimal:

```
SELECT * 
FROM listings L1, listings L2
WHERE L1.name = L2.name
AND L1.telephone = L2.telephone
AND L1.address = L2.address
AND L1.latitude = L2.latitude
AND L1.longitude = L2.longitude
```

Any suggestions, links, help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: i think your queries look ok. i assume this code is meant to sanitize a legacy db and will only be run once. in this case i would not pay too much attention to performance. in other words: where's the problem if you say this code works?

Comment: There is no problem, but Im trying to learn to optimize queries such as this because Id like to get into the habit of writing optimized queries

Comment: However, for the second query for finding duplicates that is definetly not optimized and thats the one that Id like to improve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first query doesn't have any significant performance problem. It will run with a seq scan evaluating your "is corrupt" predicate. The check for `== ''` is redundant with `length(foo) < 2` as length('') is < 2. You have a bug where you quoted the field names in your length() calls, so you'll be evaluating the length of the literal field name instead of the value of the field. You have also failed to test for NULL which is a value distinct from ''. You can use the `coalesce` function to convert NULL to '' and capture NULLS with the length check. You also don't seem to have addressed the special word based rule for address. This later is trouble unless you extend sqlite with a regexp function. I suggest approximating it with LIKE or GLOB.

Try this alternative:

```
SELECT * FROM listings
WHERE LENGTH(coalesce(telephone,'')) < 2
OR LENGTH(coalesce(fax,'')) < 2 
OR LENGTH(coalesce(city,'')) < 2 
OR LENGTH(coalesce(province,'')) < 2 
OR LENGTH(coalesce(postal_code,'')) < 2 
OR LENGTH(coalesce(latitude,'')) < 2 
OR LENGTH(coalesce(longitude,'')) < 2 
OR LENGTH(coalesce(name,'')) < 2
OR LENGTH(coalesce(address,'')) < 5
OR trim(address) not like '%__ __%'
```

You find duplicates query doesn't work, since there's always at least one record to match when self joining on equality.  You need to exclude the record under test on one side of the join. Typically this can be done by excluding on primary key.  You haven't mentioned if the table has a primary key, but IIRC sqllite can give you a proxy for one with ROWID. Something like this:

```
SELECT L1.* 
FROM listings L1
where exists (
  select null
  from listings L2
  where L1.ROWID <> L2.ROWID
  AND L1.name = L2.name
  AND L1.telephone = L2.telephone
  AND L1.address = L2.address
  AND L1.latitude = L2.latitude
  AND L1.longitude = L2.longitude
)
```

BTW, while you stressed efficiency in your question, it's important to make your code correct before you worry about efficiency.

Comment: Wow. Thanks for your excellent answer dbenhur. Thats exactly the kind of feedback that helps become a better programmer. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're doing overprocessing. As the length of the string `''` is 0 then it matches the condicion `length('') < 2`. So, you don't need to check if a field is equal to `''` as it has already been filtered by the conditions on the length function.

However, I don't see how you're checking for null values. I'd replace all the `aField = ''` with `aField is null`.